# How to enter KVM instance without IP?

Tags: openstack, qemu, kvm, libvirt, virsh

I live migrate a openstack vm instance using `virsh migrate --live  instance-00000008  qemu+tcp://nova@az02hci02:16509/system  --copy-storage-all` command. This migration is live migrtation without shared storage.

Migration is success and instance's state is `running` in destination host. But migrated instance has no ip. And destination host seems to have no network.

```
virsh net-list
 Name                 State      Autostart     Persistent
----------------------------------------------------------
```

The vm instance's interface and MAC address is:

```
virsh domiflist instance-00000008
Interface  Type       Source     Model       MAC
-------------------------------------------------------
tapd8280f0e-52 bridge     qbrd8280f0e-52 virtio      fa:16:3e:33:2b:82
```

How can i enter this vm instance without ip?

Comment: Would be useful to know if your compute host has Neutron running properly. What does say your nova-conductor logs? is there any error? Did you checked the Neutron logs in the target compute host? You should have network, unless there is something wrong with your Neutron DHCP service

Answer (score 1):

The `virsh net-list` command is reporting on libvirt virtual networks.

The `virsh domiflist` command, however, is reporting `type=bridge` which means this guest is *not* connected to a libvirt virtual network. Instead the guest is bridged to a physical NIC device. As such it will be getting an IP address assigned by whatever DHCP server is on your LAN.  This is good because it means during migration nothing should have changed for your guest. Whatever IP address it had before the migration should be the same IP address after the migration.

Comment: I create the vm instance using openstack. However, i live migrate using virsh. I can't ping the  old ip.

Comment: Definitely do *NOT* do 'virsh migrate' behind the back of openstack.

OpenStack needs to know where the VM is running at all times, in order to enable OpenStack's networking layer to correctly handle the VM's traffic.

By calling virsh migrate directly Nova / Neutron have no idea what happened to thie VM, so it is not surprising that you loose networking. You must use Nova itself to perform the migration.

Answer (score 0):

You can enter into VM using **virsh console *vmname***